# Paths in Visual Studio post-build event

Tags: visual-studio, command-line, command-line-arguments, robocopy

i have following problem: Because Visual Studio can't handle chain references, i need to copy all "chain reference"-DLLs to my program's bin-folder. For this, i use Robocopy.

The only problem is, that my command-line, i enter in Visual Studio post-build event is split incorrect.

```
ROBOCOPY "$(TargetDir)" "$(SolutionDir)Map\bin\$(ConfigurationName)\" *.dll /LOG:RCPY.log
```

This is my build event. All i get now is following:

```
Gestartet: Fri Jul 06 15:40:30 2012

Quelle : F:\Sicherung\Visual Studio\Projects\Map\Core\Core.GUI\bin\Release\ F:\Sicherung\Visual\
Ziel : F:\Sicherung\Visual Studio\Projects\Map\Core\Core.GUI\bin\Release\Studio\Projects\Map\Map\bin\Release\

Dateien : *.dll

Optionen: /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30
```

Whyever, it splits it at the empty space of "Visual Studio" in the second path/parameter.
I tried everything with the quotes, but either Robocopy isn't executed (at least the log file doesn´t get overwritten) or the i get this log entry shown thereover...

And Visual Studio shows:

> The command ... exited with code 16

which means there is a fatal error, mostly cause of invalid paths.

Comment: Is that a .NET or C++ project? If .NET set *Copy Local* to *true* or use project references, then referenced assemblies will be copied automatically to your output folder.

Comment: "Because Visual Studio can´t handle chain references"? Can you explain, I never have to copy manually dll.

Comment: Have you tried to debug paths using `echo "<combined/path"` to make sure they're correct?

Comment: Sorry. This is a .Net project. Copy Local doesnt work. I have one main project "Map". And subprojects called "Core.GUI" and so on. Core.GUI also references to third-party libraries like AvalonDock. Now if i build my whole solution, in the main project's bin-folder is only the "Core.GUI.dll" but not those DLLs which are referenced by it. Those libraries are only in "Core.GUI"'s bin-folder...

And because of this, my project never works (FileNotFoundException is thrown)...

How do i debug paths excatly?

Comment: Try the answers in this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587394/how-to-put-double-quotes-in-vs2010-post-build-step/12008312#12008312

Answer (score 10):

Unlike xcopy, robocopy treats \" an escape character, as noted on http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html:

> If either the source or desination are a "quoted long foldername" do not include a trailing backslash as this will be treated as an escape character, i.e. "C:\some path\" will fail but "C:\some path\" or "C:\some path." or "C:\some path" will work.

Since the trailing backslash is already included in post-build macros, you'll need to add a second backslash or a period to the end of your source and destination arguments:

```
ROBOCOPY "$(TargetDir)." "$(SolutionDir)Map\bin\$(ConfigurationName)\." *.dll /LOG:RCPY.log
```

I recommend adding the period, as this eliminates the escape character rather than work around it.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, but I got it working a while after I asked (2012). Thanks, nonetheless.

Comment: I figured you weren't still looking for a solution, but I wanted to post this for anyone else having this issue (like I was).