# How to put double quotes in VS2010 post build step

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build, msbuild, macros, quoting

I'm trying to create a post build file copy step in VS2010 which handles path macros when they have embedded spaces.  I've tried surrounding the copy commands in double quotes but I get error from when copy is invoked if `$(SolutionDir)` contains a space. the echoed command line in the error message does not show the double quotes.

`copy "$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\*" "$(TargetDir)"`

I also tried separately `\"` and `""` but both of these cause the 2 character escape sequence to appear in the echoed command line?  How does one properly escape a double quote in a build step?

Comment: Sorry, but why do you want to punish yourself in this way. Move your solution to a path without spaces.

Comment: Try escaping the speechmarks by using `%22` instead of `"`

Comment: @Steve Mine project location doesn't have spaces but another team member unknowingly placed his workspace under "Documents/Microsoft Visual Studio\Projects".  Looking for a solution to not having solution break based on its location.

Comment: Could you try with a batch file? Passing the arguments inside as %1 %2 and using quotation marks if needed inside the batch?

Comment: @keyboardP Tried %22 and still get error.

Error 1 The command "copy %22C:\NGLS\Debug\*%22 %22C:\NGLS\DauServer\bin\Debug\%22" exited with code 1.

Comment: @Steve I'd have the same quoting issue passing the parameters to a batch file.  The problem is I need to get VS2010 to put quotes in its command line no matter if I'm calling a batch file or a copy command.

Comment: Putting quotes around macros (as you attempted to do) should work, are you sure the failure isn't due to some other problem?  For example, `"$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)*"` should probably have a backslash between $(Configuration) and the asterisk.

Comment: In C++ projects the default value for the output Directory (aka TargetDir) is `$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\\` so unless your project has a different value for Output Directory your copy is going to copy a directory onto itself.  Assuming of course that you're building a C++ project here.

Answer (score 12):

I was having trouble using double quotes with a pre-build event command in Visual Studio.  I have seen the batch file solutions to this problem, but it seems a batch file would not solve all problems and is not elegant.  *I found the solution was to put a space before the closing double quote.*  The details are as follows.

The following command worked, but would not support spaces in the path:

`subwcrev $(SolutionDir) $(SolutionDir)subwcrev_template.txt $(SolutionDir)version.h`

I have little control over where other developers will place the solution, so I had to support spaces in the path.  Trying to use quotes around paths to support spaces, I came up with the following command.  It always fails.

`subwcrev "$(SolutionDir)" "$(SolutionDir)subwcrev_template.txt" "$(SolutionDir)version.h"`

Almost by accident, I found the solution, put a space between the last character of the path and the double quote.

`subwcrev "$(SolutionDir) " "$(SolutionDir)subwcrev_template.txt " "$(SolutionDir)version.h "`

This worked.  I tested this in AVR Studio 6.1, which uses a Visual Studio Shell.

Comment: Sweet, in VS2017 this suggestion worked whereas escaping with backslash or triple quotes or using XML entities failed utterly.

Comment: It's because `"$(SolutionDir)"` resolves to `"some folder\"` thus the escaping your quote; `"$(SolutionDir)\"` will work though.

Answer (score 10):

Visual Studio project files are XML files. Some special characters, such as the double quote, have to be escaped by using named entities. I think they're similar to what's used for encoding strings to html.

MSDN has a reference on [How To Use Reserved XML Characters in Project Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171485%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). In your example, all you would need to do to accomplish your copy is this in the .csproj/.vbproj file:

```
copy &quot;$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\*&quot; &quot;$(TargetDir)&quot;
```

That will wrap both paths in double quotes. You'll get errors when referencing paths with spaces and that's why the double quotes are required.

Comment: This doesn't work in VS2017 - "'quot' is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Comment: @SørenBoisen this answer is specific to VS2010.

Answer (score 6):

You need to put a double quote within two double quotes.

Example of a copy file in a post build step:
`copy /Y """C:\source path with spaces\somefile.txt""" """C:\destination path with spaces\"""`

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't get the other answers to work.

I finally just escaped the last "\":

```
"$(TargetDir)\"
```

Comment: I could not understand the reason of escaping the double quote but it worked.

Comment: Very rarely, we software developers have to do something just because it works. It makes you feel dirty without a logical reason to do so. But in this case, it is due to a design limitation (aka a bug). Hopefully MS will fix this in the future.

Comment: @Ali The \ isn't escaping the double quote but rather unescaping the prior trailing \ from $(TargetDir) so that it isn't interpreted as an escape character itself for the double quote and instead as a normal independent backslash.

Comment: Just to add to my previous comment, unfortunately using the C# verbatim syntax of `@` before the string, does not make \ a literal character in this context and instead just includes the `@` in the string!

Answer (score 5):

Please, oh please ***don't*** use post build events.
Instead, use the power of MSBuild's **[`AfterBuild`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171462.aspx)** target:

Right click on your project and select `Edit Project File`. Add an AfterBuild event:

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
      <FilesToCopy Include="$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\*" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(FilesToCopy)"
          DestinationFolder="$(TargetDir)"
          OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true" SkipUnchangedFiles="false" Condition="'@(FilesToCopy)' != ''" />
  </Target>
```

Unlike the PostBuildEvent which executes by raw cmd.exe, BeforeBuild/AfterBuild targets run by managed code, which ensures more robust execution, better maintainability and traceability.

Comment: Does this take care of spaces in path?

Comment: @Mrchief Yes. Spaces can also be escaped using `'%22'`

Comment: Not sure how... Assume `$(SolutionDir)` expands to `C:\Path With Spaces\src`. Care to show an example?

Comment: Then `%22$(SolutionDir)%22` will become `"C:\Path With Spaces\src"`. For the example above you don't need to escape spaces as `Copy` task takes care of it.

Comment: you can also escape the quotes (`"`) with `&quot;` in XML

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to just separate the trailing `\` from the `"` with a `.` like so:

```
"$(TargetDir)."
```

The `.` just means "the current directory" (as opposed to `..` to mean "the directory one level up from the current directory"); I've never actually had a use for it until this problem hit me too!

Answer (score 0):

I had another situation. Running a tool inside the Solution Dir with two parameters containing paths with spaces. This was my solution:

`"$(SolutionDir)Tool.exe" --solution-dir "$(SolutionDir)\" --project-dir "$(ProjectDir)\"`

Put double quotes on the inital command, use double quotes on all paths AND use a backslash before the last double quote of each path.