# Can't run post build with UnitTest++ VS2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, unittest++

I am going through the [MoneyApp](http://unittest-cpp.sourceforge.net/money_tutorial/) tutorial for UnitTest++, but I am receiving the following error when I add the postbuild settings. I am wondering if it's because of the space before (x86), does anybody know how to resolve this?

```
Error   1   error MSB3073: The command "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MoneyTestApp\Debug\MoneyTestApp.exe
:VCEnd" exited with code 9009.  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets  134 5   MoneyTestApp
```

Answer (score 0):

My suspicions were right, it was the spaces in `Visual Studio 2012` that were causing the problem, I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12008312/1821057) that escapes the spaces with three double quotes. Works fine.